# How to open an external link in a browser window using function file in Office Web add in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I want to open a tutorial link for my app in a new browser window using Function file. So far, I am able to open the link using dialog API, but that is not the requirement. I need to find a way to open the link in new browser window. I have already added the url in app domain in the manifest.

```
(function () {
  Office.initialize = function (reason) {};
})();

function openExternalLink(event) {

    //this doesn't work
    window.open('https://www.google.com/',"_blank"); 

   // this runs successfully 
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://www.google.com/', { height: 100, width: 100 });

    event.completed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window)

> Specify each domain you
>   want to open in the add-in window in the list of domains specified in
>   the AppDomains element of the manifest file. If the add-in tries to go
>   to a URL in a domain that is in the list, then it opens in the task
>   pane in both desktop Office and Office Online. If it tries to go to a
>   URL that isn't in the list, then, in desktop Office, that URL opens in
>   a new browser window (outside the add-in pane).

In your case, since you have added the domain to app domains, the url opens in add-in dialog, removing the domain from app domain should solve your issue.

Comment: It keeps showing loading on the status bar and won't do anything even when I remove address from the AppDomain.

Comment: Where are you testing your add-in? (Windows/Mac/Android/iOS/Browser ?)

Comment: I am testing on Windows by side-loading into Word 2016